# VirtualProtectEx function failing - error 487, only on Windows XP

Tags: c++, c, winapi, memory, process

Allow me to clarify, this code works 100% on Windows Vista and Windows 7, however, the function `VirtualProtectEx`  fails on Windows XP with a `GetLastError()` code of 487 - ERROR_INVALID_ADDRESS.

Here is the function associated:

```
int HpRemoteHookInstall(__in HANDLE m_hProcess, __in LPVOID m_pvTargetAddress, __in LPVOID m_pvRedirectAddress) {
// Misc checks
if ( m_pvTargetAddress == NULL || m_pvRedirectAddress == NULL )
{
    return -1;
}

DWORD  m_dwOldRights         = NULL;
BYTE   m_btHotPatch[7];

ZeroMemory(m_btHotPatch, sizeof(m_btHotPatch));

    // m_hProcess - remote process
// m_pvTargetAddress - remote base
// Allow write access - code will be restored later on
if ( VirtualProtectEx(m_hProcess, (LPVOID)m_pvTargetAddress, 6, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &m_dwOldRights) == FALSE )
{
    DisplayError(); // displays getlasterror function in messagebox
    return -2;
}
```

What could I possibly be doing wrong?
Thank you for your time.

**Edit** - The m_pvTargetAddress value is constant on each operating system (meaning the same on every execution), but differ between the three OS's

**Edit** - I obtain the m_pvTargetAddress through GetThreadContex(Remote thread) -> Eip of the context

**Edit** - Here are the values VirtualQueryEx returned when called:

**Windows XP**

- 0 - allocation base
- 0 - allocation protect
- 2088828928 - base address
- 1 - protect
- 983040 - region size
- 65536 - state
- 0 - type

**Windows 7**

- 2003959808 - allocation base
- 128 - allocation protect
- 2004025344 - base address
- 32 - protect
- 876544 - region size
- 4096 - state
- 16777216 - type

**Windows Vista**

- 2006122496 - allocation base
- 128 - allocation protect
- 2006536192 - Base address
- 32 - protect
- 389120 - region size
- 4096 - state
- 16777216 - type

Comment: Please update your question with how are you acquiring the target address and what it's value is.

Comment: Okay sure, just a second.

Comment: Just added how I obtained the address.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you print out the `m_pvTargetAddress` value, and check whether it's valid address in target address space by e.g. a debugger or ProcessExplorer etc, or call `VirtualQueryEx` to query whether the address is valid before `VirtualProtectEx` is called. another thing to check is as followed quote from MSDN:

> All pages in the specified region must be within the same reserved
>   region allocated when calling the VirtualAlloc or VirtualAllocEx
>   function using MEM_RESERVE. The pages cannot span adjacent reserved
>   regions that were allocated by separate calls to VirtualAlloc or
>   VirtualAllocEx using MEM_RESERVE.

Comment: Sorry I meant VirtualProtectEx,

Anyway, the interesting thing is when I create the suspended process, when I break through the program there is different memory amounts for each OS - 24kb for XP, 36kb for Vista, and 100kb for Windows 7.

Comment: I updated the OP with the results of the queries on both OS's

Comment: the output indicates that it's an invalid address for XP

Comment: I updated my question and gave more detail here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16882766/createprocess-function-not-working-correctly-on-windows-xp-from-setthreadconte

cheers