# How much system-provided, user-space process initialization can be bypassed?

Tags: winapi, assembly, reverse-engineering

On most x86-based Unix systems you can construct a "static" executable that does not load any system-provided DLL(-equivalent)s, and runs a bare minimum of instructions before terminating itself normally.  For instance, this works on x86/Linux (32-bit).  Technically I might not even need the second `mov` instruction, as IIRC the ABI guarantees all registers are cleared to zero at the program entrypoint.

```
$ cat > test.s
.text
.globl start
start:
    movl $1,%eax  # _exit
    movl $0,%ebx
    int $0x80
$ as -32 test.s -o test.o
$ ld -m elf_i386 -e start test.o -o test
```

My question is how close you can get on Windows to this bare minimum of instructions executed in user space between process creation and termination.  I have heard rumors that the kernelside process creation logic will load `ntdll.dll` and possibly also `kernel32.dll` into every process whether or not the PE file references them, and that both of these have nontrivial startup code that may be unavoidable.  I have also heard rumors that system call numbers are not part of the stable ABI, so you *have* to call through ntdll for cross-version compatibility, even if you're bypassing Win32.  I would like to know to what extent these rumors are true, and to what extent their implications can be worked around.

This is an exercise in what is *possible* in an experiment, rather than what is a good idea in a product shipped to end-users.  A concrete motivation for asking this question is that if it were possible to cut the "mandatory" system DLLs completely out of the loop then it would be straightforward to measure what proportion of process startup time is due to their self-initialization.

I'm not very experienced with low-level Windows programming, so if you can give a step-by-step recipe like the above for constructing the "minimal" executable you propose as your answer, that would be appreciated.

Comment: This is not a good question for this site, as it does not ask for a **practical** programming problem. If you just want to know how things work on Windows, get a copy of [Windows Internals, Part 1](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0735648735/) and [Windows Internals, Part 2](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0735665877/). With that out of the way: You cannot bypass the bootstrapping code inside ntdll.dll, that performs process initialization. When the kernel creates a process object, it copies the least little amount of information into its address space, and then transfers control to the bootstrapping code.

Comment: [Creating the smallest possible PE executable](https://web.archive.org/web/20150906122804/http://www.phreedom.org/research/tinype/)

Comment: @MichaelPetch I've seen that.  It is about making the PE *file size* as small as possible, and makes no attempt to short-circuit anything from the system DLLs.

Comment: @IInspectable I don't see how this is not a practical programming problem, and I'd like some evidence for the assertion that the ntdll bootstrap cannot be bypassed, please.  (Ideally at less than book-length.)

Comment: Kernel32 will always be mapped into the memory space of the process, since that's what actually loads and starts the process. See also [Program with no dependencies](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2092/program-with-no-dependencies) though given what you wrote `I'm not very experienced with low-level Windows programming` I'd say you are starting at the wrong end of the learning curve.

Comment: Hmmm.  Nothing you can do in the *code* of the new process executable will make any difference, because process initialization happens before any of the code from your executable is run.  Obviously you can remove the DLL dependencies as per dxiv's link and that will prevent any non-mandatory DLLs from being loaded.  Other than that you'd have to resort to fiddling about with header flags and seeing if any of them do anything much.  It is unlikely, because from MS's POV what would be the point of a flag saying "don't bother to initialize me, I don't plan to do anything"?

Comment: Somewhat relevant: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150716-00/?p=45131

Comment: @dxiv: *kernel32.dll* is not necessarily mapped into a newly created process. Process initialization is performed through *ntdll.dll* (which is always mapped into a newly created process' address space).

Comment: A more plausible line of attack might be the way in which you launch the process, i.e., try using ZwCreateProcess, or create the process suspended and mess about with it somehow before resuming.  But I'm not sure what you're trying to measure.  I don't think there's any meaningful distinction between "mandatory DLL initialization" and "process initialization".  (Unless you're talking about your program's initialization, in which case why don't you just start the timer when your code first starts up?)  And of course if you don't let the system DLLs initialize, the API won't work properly.

Comment: @IInspectable: IIRC there's a bunch of DLLs that are loaded by ntdll.dll whether or not you ask for them, isn't kernel32.dll one of them?  I may be mistaken, since this wouldn't have been what I was looking for at the time.

Comment: Also *possibly* relevant; https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897447.aspx

Comment: @HarryJohnston: I was referring to a newly created process, that hasn't run any code yet (as outlined in the blog entry you linked to). I believe at that point, there's only *ntdll.dll* mapped into the address space of that process. Once *ntdll.dll*'s entry point runs, it performs process initialization and does load required modules. *kernel32.dll* may be one of the modules, that always gets loaded.

Comment: @IInspectable: sounds right.  I did try to follow process initialization through a debugger once, when [one of my programs was crashing before it started](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30659232/why-do-my-crt-free-applications-intermittently-crash-on-startup) but I don't think I've kept any records of what little I discovered.  That executable would have been explicitly linking ntkernel.dll anyway, so not really relevant I guess.

Comment: @IInspectable `kernel32.dll is not necessarily mapped into a newly created process` It used to be the case in old NTs up to at least XP as far as I remember. See for example this reply in an old thread [Kernel32 base address](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/microsoft.public.win32.programmer.kernel/kn6-yNMkvyY/jSmGmG4db5AJ) and Slava's following reply as well. Any pointers to changes in this behavior in recent Windows would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @dxiv: I'm not aware of any changes, but we are referring to different stages in process initialization. A newly created process that hasn't run any code yet doesn't have any modules (other than *ntdll.dll*) mapped into its address space. Both of your links refer to a process, where *ntdll.dll* has already performed preliminary initialization and started loading modules (*ntdll.dll* is responsible for creating and initializing the structures required for loading modules).

Comment: @IInspectable Fair point. However, this is a more recent post which suggests that _something_ did in fact change after XP: [Newly created suspended process's EIP is failing only on Windows XP - EIP under kernal32.dll image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16882766/newly-created-suspended-processs-eip-is-failing-only-on-windows-xp-eip-under).

Comment: @HarryJohnston Are you saying that no matter what the PE header for the main executable says its entry point is, the kernel will always transfer control to a hardcoded entry point in ntdll(?) first? (ELF-based systems are not like that, so it's somewhat alien to me.)

Comment: Basically, yes.  If I understand correctly, when the new process is created, the initial instruction pointer is inside ntdll.dll.  (So not a transfer of control per se, but that's just a quibble.)  But I thought UNIX did something quite similar, in that very new process is a copy of an existing one, which then calls exec() to load the new executable?  The startup code in ntdll.dll performs the same function as exec(), the only conceptual difference being that the parent executable doesn't have to call it explicitly.

Comment: ELF based systems aren't actually that much different. Normally the OS doesn't transfer control to the entry point given in the ELF executable's header either. Instead it loads the interpreter (eg `ld.so`) given in the header and transfers control to its entry point. This is how ELF based system implement dynamic linking, `ld.so` does all the work. ELF is more flexible in that you can choose what interpreter to use, or not to use one and jump directly to the entry point, but in practice it usually works much like Windows.

Answer (score 4):

I might be able to answer part of your question, but I don't know (and I doubt) that you can bypass them.

> I have also heard rumors that system call numbers are not part of the
>   stable ABI, so you have to call through ntdll for cross-version
>   compatibility, even if you're bypassing Win32

This is true, each major kernel version comes with newer system calls numbers.

The reason why the syscalls number are not permanent is that the syscall table is generated by name (not by number). So each time you insert a new syscall the older ones get "pushed" farther (and the other way around if a syscall gets removed, although this is quite rare).

The syscall table name (kernel side) is `KiServiceTable` (part of `KeServiceDescriptorTable` and `KeServiceDescriptorTableShadow`).

```
kd> dps nt!KeServiceDescriptorTable L4
fffff800`1236ba80  fffff800`1215f700 nt!KiServiceTable
fffff800`1236ba88  00000000`00000000
fffff800`1236ba90  00000000`000001b1
fffff800`1236ba98  fffff800`1216048c nt!KiArgumentTable
```

There are 0x1B1 system calls (windows 8.1) and the system calls pointers are located in the `KiServiceTable`.

An userland syscall stub look like this (Windows 10):

```
0:004> u ntdll!ntcreatefile
ntdll!NtCreateFile:
00007fff`1d913ac0 4c8bd1          mov     r10,rcx   ; args
00007fff`1d913ac3 b855000000      mov     eax,55h   ; syscall number
00007fff`1d913ac8 0f05            syscall           ; x64 instruction, perform ring3 -> ring0 transition
00007fff`1d913aca c3              ret
00007fff`1d913acb 0f1f440000      nop     dword ptr [rax+rax]
```

The same one from Windows 8.1 x64:

```
0:003> u ntdll!ntcreatefile
ntdll!NtCreateFile:
00007ff8`62071720 4c8bd1          mov     r10,rcx
00007ff8`62071723 b854000000      mov     eax,54h
00007ff8`62071728 0f05            syscall
00007ff8`6207172a c3              ret
00007ff8`6207172b 0f1f440000      nop     dword ptr [rax+rax]
```

As you can see the same function leads to different syscall numbers (0x55 for Windows 10 and 0x54 for Windows 8.1)

Pointers in the syscall table (inside the kernel) are now "encoded" in a simple way (they were plain pointers before). Let's take a look at index 0x54:

```
kd> ? nt!KiServiceTable+(dwo(nt!KiServiceTable + 0x54 * 4) >> 4)
Evaluate expression: -8795786429460 = fffff800`12463bec
```

What symbols is at this address?

```
kd> ln fffff800`12463bec
Browse module
Set bu breakpoint

(fffff800`12463bec)   nt!NtCreateFile   |  (fffff800`12463c70)   nt!IopCreateFile
Exact matches:
    nt!NtCreateFile (<no parameter info>)
```

So `ntdll!ntcreatefile` leads to kernel function `nt!NtCreateFile` (not a big surprise :)

You can find a syscall table for major Windows systems [at this URL](http://j00ru.vexillium.org/ntapi_64/).

Actually, the [leaked source](https://github.com/hacksysteam/WRK-1.2/blob/master/base/ntos/ke/i386/systable.asm) from the windows XP kernel (in fact the WRK) shows how the service table is generated (in an assembly file).

> I have heard rumors that the kernelside process creation logic will
>   load ntdll.dll and possibly also kernel32.dll into every process
>   whether or not the PE file references them, and that both of these
>   have nontrivial startup code that may be unavoidable

That's true. I'll not go through the whole process which is very complicated and discussed to great length in the **Windows Internals** books .

`ntdll` is loaded because a big part of the user-land windows loader is located there (if you have symbolic information, look at all the function starting with `Ldr`).

The `kernel32.dll` is also loaded inside process address space because part of the main thread initialization is located there. It is also needed because a part of exception handling is done there.

I could have gone with an executable that execute just a single instruction (namely `RET` on x86 / x64), but the result is the same with notepad.

Put a breakpoint at entry point:

```
0:000> bp $exentry
0:000> bl
0 e 00007ff6`275c4030     0001 (0001)  0:**** notepad!WinMainCRTStartup
0:000> g
Breakpoint 0 hit
notepad!WinMainCRTStartup:
00007ff6`275c4030 4883ec28        sub     rsp,28h
```

Stack trace at entry:

```
0:000> kb
 # RetAddr           : Args to Child                                                           : Call Site
00 00007fff`1ce62d92 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : notepad!WinMainCRTStartup
01 00007fff`1d889f64 : 00007fff`1ce62d70 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x22
02 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x34
```

So we have `ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart` which calls `KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk`which calls the entry point of the executable.

```
0:000> u KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk L 10
KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk:
00007fff`1ce62d70 48895c2408      mov     qword ptr [rsp+8],rbx
00007fff`1ce62d75 57              push    rdi
00007fff`1ce62d76 4883ec20        sub     rsp,20h
00007fff`1ce62d7a 498bf8          mov     rdi,r8
00007fff`1ce62d7d 488bda          mov     rbx,rdx
00007fff`1ce62d80 85c9            test    ecx,ecx
00007fff`1ce62d82 7517            jne     KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x2b (00007fff`1ce62d9b)
00007fff`1ce62d84 488bca          mov     rcx,rdx
00007fff`1ce62d87 ff15d3390600    call    qword ptr [KERNEL32!_guard_check_icall_fptr (00007fff`1cec6760)]
00007fff`1ce62d8d 488bcf          mov     rcx,rdi
00007fff`1ce62d90 ffd3            call    rbx  ; call entry point
00007fff`1ce62d92 8bc8            mov     ecx,eax
00007fff`1ce62d94 ff15be2f0600    call    qword ptr [KERNEL32!_imp_RtlExitUserThread (00007fff`1cec5d58)]
00007fff`1ce62d9a cc              int     3
```

As you can see, returning from the entry point calls `KERNEL32!_imp_RtlExitUserThread` (which calls ExitProcess() for the main thread).

Answer (score 2):

The closest you can get to the initialization itself is with TLS callbacks as far as i'm aware, [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6yh4a9k1.aspx) is some explanation on how things work; TLS callbacks are execute before the entry point of the application and they do have some limitations (that can be worked around with some effort).

As to measure startup time you should avoid trying to do it inside your own aplication; a separated process would be best for that (A debugger could do the trick in a much more reliable way).

Regarding a minimal executable, you can build an executable with only RET (as mentioned by @Neitsa); windows will load the program on memory but will not execute anything, it will basically only map things to memory and that's all.

With [FASM](http://flatassembler.net/) you can build an exe that does literally nothing, like the following:

```
include '%fasm%\win32ax.inc'

section 'a' code readable executable

start:
retn
.end start
```

Comment: +1 for a very interesting idea!  [This](http://www.nynaeve.net/?p=186) doesn't say where the executable module TLS initializers fits into the initialization sequence, so it might be quite early on, although if so that means you would need to be extra careful about what API calls you make.